# Strange result with Python decimal module

Tags: python

In the following code:

```
>>> round(Decimal('0.755'), 2)
0.76
>>> round(Decimal('0.735'), 2)
0.73
```

why is `round(Decimal('0.735'), 2)` not `0.74`?

Comment: 5 second search away : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

Comment: The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, per the [quick-start tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial):

```
>>> round(a, 1)     # round() first converts to binary floating point
1.3
```

so the decimal object is converted back to a float *then* rounded, giving you the behaviour you were presumably using decimals to avoid. Instead, you should use the [`.quantize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) method:

```
>>> Decimal('0.735').quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
Decimal('0.74')
```